# Is it possible to set up MW3 to run fullscreen on the secondary monitor?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, monitor

In BF3 I can choose which monitor to use for fullscreen gaming. Since my secondary monitor is my plasma TV, this is a great feature.

MW3 instead offers video modes for the primary screen only, so that I have to switch the screen in windows (set the plasma primary) before I start the game.

Does anybody know a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

The game probably snaps natively to the system's main display.

You can try 2 things:

- Try and edit the `config.cfg` or `config_ms.cfg` file (you can find it in the install folder). It may have some settings regarding display.
- switch your main display between your PC and your plasma. The game will snap to your plasma screen that is now set up as the main screen. You could try looking in your GPU's control panel. You may have game specific settings there.